# NOR gate turned into a LED killer

Tags: led, logic-gates

I'm trying to build a simple NOR gate, but I've accidentaly made it so that whenever all the switches are off the LED is on, but when I close one of the switches, the LED simply dies.

This is the circuit I have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvORhg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I figured that I might need a resistor at NODE1, but when I do use a resistor, the light gets even brighter when I close one of the switches.

Comment: Why is your circuit upside down? Always make ground point downwards, and positive supplies upwards. This was really confusing to read at first!

Comment: According to your schematic, you operate your LED in reverse bias. That won't work and has the potential to damage the diode. Is this just a drawing mistake, or actually the case?

Comment: The LED is reverse biased in your schematic so it can't be turning on. However, the maximum allowed reverse bias is only 5 volts which may explain why it dies when you throw a switch.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Didn't know that! Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MarcusMüller no that's just a drawing mistake. The LED actually turns on.

Comment: This is so confusing! Signal flow should also be as far as possible from left to right, and unless you have a very good reason, keep transistor bars vertical! You must have manually rotated almost everything in your schematic - wasn't that just annoying to do?

Comment: Ok so we have a schematic that doesn't actually reflect the circuit. Could you maybe redraw it with grounds pointing down, transistors upright, and the LED on the right end? Would really make it easier to understand - these are really just conventions, but humans work a lot by recognizing known patterns :) thanks for being here by the way, I know I'm a bit of a pain right now!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I was pretty much recreating what was on my breadboard. I'll edit the question to change the schematic.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fixed the schematic. At least I hope.

Comment: You need resistors (1K or so) in series between the switches and transistor bases to limit base current - without them you will probably destroy the transistors.  Is the 1N4148 intended to represent the LED?  Use an LED symbol, please.

Comment: @PeterBennett Just did those changes. However, it doesn't really change anything about the NOR gate. Do you happen to find any other issue. If not, maybe it's a hardware issue and I need to try with different transistors.

Comment: It's not possible for that circuit to damage LEDs. Either both transistors are off so LED lights up, or, one or more tranaistors are on so LED will be off. It is likely that the schematic does not match what you built. E.g. transistors may be connected wrong in your actual circuit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit isn't the problem. The transistors I was using were fried. Changing them for different ones solved the issue.

Comment: (See [Peter Bennet's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660417/nor-gate-turned-into-a-led-killer#comment1756387_660417).)